# Can't connect to database in Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, database, sequel

I have problem with connecting to Sequel Pro. It shows this:

**Unable to connect via the socket, or the request timed out.

Double-check that the socket path is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, and that the server is running.

MySQL said: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)**

Sequel Pro used to work properly but after I found out there is a database Sequel Ace I tried to connect to this database. That's where the problem started. I uninstalled Sequel Ace but Sequel Pro still doesn't work.

Can you help me with this problem please?

Thank you!

I tried to uninstall Sequel Ace and Sequel Pro, but it didn't help. I tried this line in terminal: **% sudo brew services stop mysql** and then this: **% brew services start mysql**.

Comment: see if you have a backup, that you can recover from

Comment: also che3kc the mysql error log, if there are hint, why it was not started

Comment: *Unable to connect via the socket, or the request timed out* means your MySQL (or maybe MariaDB) *server* is not running (or maybe it's running but not listening for connections on its socket). Please [edit] your question to clarify your configuration (server, then client like Sequel Pro.